# Couldn't start hadoop datanode normally

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

i am trying to install hadoop 2.2.0 i am getting following kind of error while starting dataenode services please help me resolve this issue.Thanks in Advance.

**2014-03-11 08:48:16,406 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Lock on /home/prassanna/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/datanode/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 3627@prassanna-Studio-1558
2014-03-11 08:48:16,426 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for block pool Block pool BP-611836968-127.0.1.1-1394507838610 (storage id DS-1960076343-127.0.1.1-50010-1394127604582) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in /home/prassanna/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/datanode: namenode clusterID = CID-fb61aa70-4b15-470e-a1d0-12653e357a10; datanode clusterID = CID-8bf63244-0510-4db6-a949-8f74b50f2be9
    at** org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.doTransition(DataStorage.java:391)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:837)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:808)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:280)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:664)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-03-11 08:48:16,427 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Ending block pool service for: Block pool BP-611836968-127.0.1.1-1394507838610 (storage id DS-1960076343-127.0.1.1-50010-1394127604582) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
2014-03-11 08:48:16,532 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Removed Block pool BP-611836968-127.0.1.1-1394507838610 (storage id DS-1960076343-127.0.1.1-50010-1394127604582)
2014-03-11 08:48:18,532 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exiting Datanode
2014-03-11 08:48:18,534 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
2014-03-11 08:48:18,536 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at prassanna-Studio-1558/127.0.1.1

Comment: There are no errors shown in your question. Please check the NameNode and DataNode log files.

Comment: i had posted my datanode logs please tell how to resolve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That simply shows that the datanode tried to startup but took some exception and died.

Please check the datanode log under the logs folder in the hadoop installation folder (unless you changed that config) for exceptions. It usually points to a configuration issue of some kind, esp. network settings (/etc/hosts) related but there are quite a few possibilities.

Comment: Please format, delete and recreate your datanode, namenode folders and try again.

Comment: Hi 
rmdir -p yarn_data,mkdir -p yarn_data,bin/hadoop namenode -format,i tried this 3 commands ,but still i am facing the same issue.actually while i am trying see the contents of datanode,namenode folder from UI before using rmdir yarn_data cmd ,i only able to see namenode contents and not allowed to see datanode contents, datanode folder showing ur not owner to access this,so ,may be due to access issue also causing this issue.Please help to solve.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are ready with correct configuration and right path.
This is a link for [Running Hadoop](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) on ubuntu.

I have used this link to setup hadoop in my machine and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Refer this,

1.Check JAVA_HOME---

```
    readlink -f $(which java) 
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

2.If JAVA is not available install by command

```
    sudo apt-get install defalul-jdk
```

than run 1. and check on terminal

```
    java -version 
    javac -version
```

3.Configure SSH

Hadoop requires SSH access to manage its nodes, i.e. remote machines plus your local machine if you want to use Hadoop on it (which is what we want to do in this short tutorial). For our single-node setup of Hadoop, we therefore need to configure SSH access to localhost for the user .

```
    sudo apt-get install ssh
    sudo su hadoop
    ssh-keygen -t rsa -P “”
    cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
    ssh localhost
```

Download and extract hadoop-2.7.3(Chosse dirrectory having read write permisson)

Set Environment Variable

```
    sudo gedit .bashrc
    source .bashrc
```

Setup Configuration Files

The following files will have to be modified to complete the Hadoop setup:

```
~/.bashrc   (Already done)
(PATH)/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh 
(PATH)/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml 
(PATH)/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml.template 
(PATH)/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xm

gedit (PATH)/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

gedit (PATH)/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml:
```

The `(HOME)/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml` file contains configuration properties that Hadoop uses when starting up. 
This file can be used to override the default settings that Hadoop starts with.

```
    ($ sudo mkdir -p /app/hadoop/tmp)
```

Open the file and enter the following in between the `<configuration></configuration>` tag:

```
gedit /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml 
<configuration> 
 <property> 
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name> 
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value> 
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description> 
 </property> 

 <property> 
  <name>fs.default.name</name> 
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value> 
  <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose 
  scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The 
  uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming 
  the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to 
  determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description> 
 </property> 
</configuration>


(PATH)/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml
```

By default, the `(PATH)/etc/hadoop/` folder contains `(PATH)/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml.template` file which has to be renamed/copied with the name `mapred-site.xml`:

```
cp /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml.template /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml
```

The mapred-site.xml file is used to specify which framework is being used for MapReduce.

We need to enter the following content in between the `<configuration></configuration>` tag:

```
    <configuration> 
     <property> 
      <name>mapred.job.tracker</name> 
      <value>localhost:54311</value> 
      <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs 
      at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map 
      and reduce task. 
      </description> 
     </property> 
    </configuration>

(PATH)/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml
```

The `(PATH)/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml` file needs to be configured for each host in the cluster that is being used.

It is used to specify the directories which will be used as the namenode and the datanode on that host.

Before editing this file, we need to create two directories which will contain the namenode and the datanode for this Hadoop installation. 
This can be done using the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode 
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode
```

Open the file and enter the following content in between the `<configuration></configuration>` tag:

```
    gedit (PATH)/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml 

    <configuration> 
     <property> 
      <name>dfs.replication</name> 
      <value>1</value> 
      <description>Default block replication. 
      The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created. 
      The default is used if replication is not specified in create time. 
      </description> 
     </property> 
     <property> 
       <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name> 
       <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value> 
     </property> 
     <property> 
       <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name> 
       <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value> 
     </property> 
    </configuration>
```

Format the New Hadoop Filesystem

Now, the Hadoop file system needs to be formatted so that we can start to use it. The format command should be issued with write permission since it creates current directory under `/usr/local/hadoop_store/` folder:

```
    bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

or

```
    bin/hdfs namenode -format
```

HADOOP SETUP IS DONE

Now start the hdfs

```
start-dfs.sh
start-yarn.sh
```

CHECK URL:  `http://localhost:50070/`

FOR STOPPING HDFS

```
stop-dfs.sh
stop-yarn.sh
```