# Hadoop cannot start Yarn

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am new to Hadoop and I am trying to start Yarn daemon by using start-yarn.sh.
Below are my config files:

core-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- core-site.xml -->
<configuration>
  <property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- hdfs-site.xml -->
<configuration>
  <property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- mapred-site.xml -->
<configuration>
  <property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- yarn-site.xml -->
<configuration>
  <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
      <value>localhost</value>
      </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I could start dfs and historyserver properly with:
`dfs-start.sh --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR` (my config files)
`mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR start historyserver`.

Both `http://localhost:50070/` and `http://localhost:19888` give me the correct pages. I try to run script s`tart-yarn.sh --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR`, here is the output in the console:

```
start-yarn.sh --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR 
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/logs/yarn-yyang-resourcemanager-yyang-ubuntu.out
2017-03-26 17:37:31,051 INFO  [main] resourcemanager.ResourceManager (StringUtils.java:startupShutdownMessage(619)) - STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting ResourceManager
STARTUP_MSG:   host = yyang-ubuntu/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.5.2
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/conf_local/hadoop:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/conf_local/hadoop:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/conf_local/hadoop:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.5.2-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.5.2-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.5.2-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.5.2/conf_local/hadoop/rm-config/log4j.properties
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r cc72e9b000545b86b75a61f4835eb86d57bfafc0; compiled by 'jenkins' on 2014-11-14T23:45Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_121
************************************************************/
```

The output seems ok to me (maybe I did not see the error). The resource manager's web UI  does not give me the correct page (the site cannot be reached). But jps gives me:

```
6081 Jps
5554 JobHistoryServer
4443 SecondaryNameNode
4237 NameNode
```

which does not included resource manager.
I use the configuration from book Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, 4th Edition

Please help me fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Refer this for installation issue:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240488/couldnt-start-hadoop-datanode-normally/45671270#45671270
```

Meanwhile put only this under your yarn-site.xml
**

```
<property> 
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name> 
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value> 
</property>
```

and mapred-site.xml should be:

```
**<property> 
      <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name> 
      <value>yarn</value> 
   </property>**
```

**
and restart hadoop: